Получить параметры с которыми вызван метод C# - типы, имена и значения
В методе c# получить сведения о том с какими параметрами значение переменных через .ToString() был вызван этот метод, независимо от количества параметров. Вызов функции должен быть одинаковым, без ручного перечисления параметров метода.
примерно так: (здесь не хватает ЗНАЧЕНИЙ всех параметров, есть только ТИПЫ)
using System.Reflection

    // Это вызов логера. в нем не надо каждый раз переписывать список переданных параметров. 
    ParameterInfo[] args = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
    MY_Debug_Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,args,this);
    // 
    
        void MY_Debug_Log(string message, ParameterInfo[] args, Object obj)
        {
            string s = "";
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("(");
            foreach (ParameterInfo p in args)
            {
                sb.Append(s);
                sb.Append(p.ParameterType.ToString());
                s = ", ";
            }
            sb.Append(")");
            Log(sb.ToString(),obj);
        }


https://stackoverflow.com/q/492600/5045688 - кратко: никак (почти).

Console.WriteLine(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()); - выводит практически то же, что и ваш метод MY_Debug_Log.

@Alex_4x если вы ищете, как собрать автоматом значения аргументов, то это не возможно. Точнее возможно, но придется наворачивать серьёзные костыли именно на реализацию класса. То что вы ищете назвается перехватчики вызова метода - интерцепторы. То есть в теории это конечно же возможно, я полагаю.

https://www.postsharp.net/il/logging вот например.

См. MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody и MethodDecorator.Fody

Бред какой то. Элементарнейшая задача. Нужно всего то получить значения входных переменных, зная их названия. (названия параметров через рефлексию можно получить). Или все входные параметры метода получить в виде массива Object[]

Дело в том, что рефлексия ничего не знает о значениях аргументов метода. Названия да, типы да, значения нет. Перехват значений можно сделать с помощью кодогенератора, который при сборке перепишет класс так, чтобы в каждом методе появилось нужное логирование. А так, значения аргументов метода знает только отладчик, возможно при подключенном отладчике у него можно запросить данные. Проще всего конечно использовать готовое решение, либо хардкодить логирование явно.

Может, вот такой костыль вам нужен? Тут правда типов нету.

Знаете как это звучит? Это звучит так, что нет элементарнейшей функции, чего быть не может. Не важно, рефлексией или как-то ешё. Есть Stack trace, в нем точно есть данные, проблема в том, что они там в бинарном массиве, а мне нужно в виде Object[]

@Alex_4x: Наоборот, это естественно для языка, который заботится о производительности. Типы параметров функции вы можете получить при помощи рефлексии без проблем. Но вот чтобы вам откуда-то достать значения, рантайму придётся конструировать ParameterInfo, а это вовсе не дешёвая операция. Поэтому C# таким не занимается.

Stack trace-а может и не быть, если оптимизатор заинлайнит функцию. Кроме того, само создание объекта StackTrace — достаточно дорогое удовольствие.

@VladD , спасибо за ссылку на то, что ты назвал костыль. Это самое близкое к тому что я искал. От того, что операция не заточена под быстрое выполнение - не повод к тому, чтобы её не было. Я шокирован тем, что такая тривиальная и логичная задача не имеет простого и ясного синтаксиса для решения. В моем случае написанное на C# используется в Unity. Unity этот код через интерпретатор mono превращает в IL код, а потом il2cpp переводит IL код в cpp который компилируются в нативное приложение. Тут речь идет не о скорости, а о стандарте C#.

К сожалению в Unity using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; не поддерживается. Может есть другой способ?

@Alex_4x: А какая версия .NET в Unity? По идее, фичи зависят от версии фреймворка и версии языка.

В Unity поддерживается стандарт C# 9.0, По сути не Unity определяет поддерживаемый стандарт, а компилятор, который использует Unity https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn

@VladD .NET Standard 2 / Framewok 4 в зависимости от выбранного профиля сборки

@Alex_4x что не так с готовыми библиотеками? Не поддкрживаются в Unity? А вообще надо бы в тегах вопроса указывать хотя-бы версию .NET.

Ещё есть решения типа Metalama/Postsharp

Аспектно-ориентированное программирование

А вот, кстати, и пример генерации кода подъехал...

Итак, решение с проксимизацией.
Сначала сделаем проксимизатор с нужными функциями:
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp2;

internal class LoggingDecorator<T> : DispatchProxy {
    private T _decorated;
    protected override object Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, object[] args) {
        try {
            LogBefore(targetMethod, args);
            var result = targetMethod.Invoke(_decorated, args);
            LogAfter(targetMethod, args, result);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is TargetInvocationException) {
            LogException(ex.InnerException ?? ex, targetMethod);
            throw ex.InnerException ?? ex;
        }
    }
    public static T Create(T decorated) {
        object proxy = Create<T, LoggingDecorator<T>>();
        ((LoggingDecorator<T>)proxy).SetParameters(decorated);
        return (T)proxy;
    }
    private void SetParameters(T decorated) {
        if (decorated == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(decorated)); }
        _decorated = decorated;
    }
    private void LogException(Exception exception, MethodInfo methodInfo = null) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Class {_decorated.GetType().FullName}, Method {methodInfo.Name} threw exception:\n{exception}");
    }
    private void LogAfter(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] args, object result) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Class {_decorated.GetType().FullName}, Method {methodInfo.Name} executed, Output: {result}");
    }
    private void LogBefore(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Class {_decorated.GetType().FullName}, Method {methodInfo.Name} is executing");
        Console.WriteLine($"Arguments types {string.Join("; ", args.Select(s => s.GetType().Name))}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Arguments values {string.Join("; ", args)}");
    }
}

Теперь используем его в простейшем примере:
internal interface ICalculator {
    int Add(int a, int b);
}
internal class Calculator : ICalculator {
    public int Add(int a, int b) => a + b; // никаких лишних команд вообще!
}
internal class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        ICalculator calculator = new Calculator(); // (1) обычный объект
        Console.WriteLine(calculator.Add(3, 5)); // (2) обычный вызов
        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 80));
        calculator = LoggingDecorator<ICalculator>.Create(new Calculator()); // (3) прокси-объект, тип переменной не изменился!
        Console.WriteLine(calculator.Add(3, 5)); // (4) прокси-объект, но обычный вызов!
    }
}

-->

8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Class ConsoleApp2.Calculator, Method Add is executing
Arguments types Int32; Int32
Arguments values 3; 5
Class ConsoleApp2.Calculator, Method Add executed, Output: 8
8

Как мы видим по строкам (2) и (4), разницы в работе с объектом нет, и тип переменной совпадает. Только инициализация объекта отличается - (1) и (3).
Различные библиотеки проксимизации предлагаю разную реализацию с использованием как интерфейсов, так и виртуальных методов. Возможно, есть и с полной реализацией, все не смотрел.

Значения получить можно так:
using System.Reflection

void AnyMethod(ArgType1 arg1, ArgType2 arg2) {
    // Это вызов логера. в нем не надо каждый раз переписывать список переданных параметров. 
    ParameterInfo[] args = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().GetParameters();
    MY_Debug_Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, args, [arg1, arg2], this);
    // 
}    
        void MY_Debug_Log(string message, ParameterInfo[] args, object[] vals, Object obj)
        {
            string s = "";
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("(");
            int i = 0;
            s = ", ";
            foreach (ParameterInfo p in args)
            {
                sb.Append(s);
                sb.Append(p.ParameterType.ToString());
                sb.Append(" = ");
                sb.Append(vals[i++].ToString());
            }
            sb.Append(")");
            Log(sb.ToString(),obj);
        }

P. S. Если всё так серьёзно (возможно, что ТТ сделаны для другого ЯП), то Вы можете использовать технологию прокси-объектов: "If you prefer not to reinvent the wheel, consider using libraries like Castle's DynamicProxy1. They simplify dynamic proxy creation and offer additional features."
Как пример, см. RealProxy in dotnet core?
P. P. S. А чтобы не ошибиться со списком аргументов, их нужно вставлять с помощью кодогенерации при постобработке, пример тут.

В требовании к реализации четко, однозначно и ясно указано - что нужно избежать такого синтаксиса, когда нужно при каждом вызове переписывать этот вызова, перечислять передаваемые параметры. То что вы предлагаете данному требованию не соответствует, так как параметры arg1, arg2 - нужно вручную вписать в вызываемый метод и следовательно: это трудоемко, может быть ошибка написания, могут быть пропущены параметры, может быть изменена последовательность параметров. Если этот массив будет заполнятся каким-то циклом и в ручную вписывать названия переменных будет ненужно - тогда это решение подойдет.

Тогда могу предложить вам использовать технологию прокси-объектов, см. дополнение к ответу. Очень работоспособное решение.

Если исходить из закидонов в ТТ, то вы вполне можете использовать шаблон проектирования "внедрение зависимостей", и приторочить туда проксимирование будет очень легко.

Спасибо за ваше участие. Я вижу следующие критичные недочеты в предложенном подходе:

Меняется семантика вызова каждого метода.
Рефакторинг кода будет требоваться в строке каждого вызова.
Код вызовов становится ужасным и совершенно не читаемым.
Через внедрение зависимостей вызов самих методов не изменить. Всё что делается через внедрение зависимостей по определению может быть решено прямым назначением эвента внутри модуля, здесь же речь идет о "оборачивании" вызова самого метода.

Велосипедист с аквалангом и дельтапланом пытается спуститься в шахту на лифте.

1 - нет; 2 - нет; 3 - нет; 4 - через внедрение зависимостей нужно будет возвращать не объект, а его прокси; вызов методов не меняется.

Если вы не использовали проксимизацию, то посмотрите. Там ничего менять не нужно, только создание объекта.

С проксимизацией вы избавитесь даже от этих двух строчек ParameterInfo[] args ... ,args,this); в каждом вашем методе.

Как правильно написали в комментариях, это задача практически нерешаемая, если нельзя модифицировать сигнатуру/вызов исследуемого метода. Это связано с тем, что оптимизирующий JIT-компилятор может генерировать разный код для передачи параметров: через регистры или через стек, может вообще ликвидировать вызов метода и вставить все его тело в конечный метод. Из-за этого всей необходимой информации, чтобы сопоставить значение параметра в памяти с соответствующим ParameterInfo, может во время выполнения не хватать. Если же перестроить вызов исследуемого метода так, чтобы эта информация всегда сохранялась, задача действительно становится элементарной.
Можно, например, создать такой вспомогательный класс для вызова метода с сохранением таблицы соответствия параметров (данная реализация поддерживает только статические методы):
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;

class ParameterMap
{
    public MethodInfo TargetMethod { get; set; }
    public object[] Args { get; set; }
}

class LoggingInvoker
{
    public static object Invoke(MethodInfo mi, params object[] args)
    {
        ParameterMap map = new ParameterMap();
        map.TargetMethod = mi;
        map.Args = args;
        List<object> finalArgs = new List<object>(args.Length + 1);
        finalArgs.Add(map);
        finalArgs.AddRange(args);

        return mi.Invoke(null, finalArgs.ToArray());
    }
}

Сам исследуемый метод нужно определить так, чтобы первым аргументом был ParameterMap. Если мы хотим создать метод для сложения чисел с логированием, определим его так:
class Program
{
    static void MY_Debug_Log(string message, ParameterMap map)
    {
        string s = "";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(message);
        sb.Append("(");
        ParameterInfo[] pars = map.TargetMethod.GetParameters();

        for(int i=0;i<pars.Length-1;i++)
        {
            ParameterInfo p = pars[i+1];
            sb.Append(s);
            sb.Append(p.ParameterType.ToString() + " ");
            sb.Append(p.Name);
            sb.Append('=');
            sb.Append(map.Args[i].ToString());
            s = ", ";
        }

        sb.Append(")");

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }

    public static double CalcSum(ParameterMap pmap, double x, double y)
    {
        MY_Debug_Log(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, pmap);

        return x + y;
    }
}

Тогда вызвать его можно так:
object res = LoggingInvoker.Invoke(typeof(Program).GetMethod("CalcSum"), 1.1, 2.2);

Выведет CalcSum(System.Double x=1.1, System.Double y=2.2)
